# How to split a string in java which has comparison operators

Tags: java, regex, split, protobuf-java

I am using string in the below format where i need to iterate the strings seperated by ",":

```
<field_path1><operator1><value1/regex1>,<field_path2><operator2><value2/regex2>
```

ex: fare.details.type!="AB", id.name.first=="QWERT"

fare.details.type is a field defined in a protobuf file.

First i split the string using "," to get different conditions and then I tried to split the string using delimeter as the operators "==", "!=" and "~=".

```
String[] operator = string.split("==|\\!=|\~=");
```

In the end i need to do a comparison of the string in the below format. Using the split operator i don't get the exact operator which is used exactly in the string.

```
if (fare.details.type!="AB")
```

Please help if anyone knows how to approach it or if can split it it some other way.

Comment: `str.split("((?<=!=)|(?=!=))|((?<===)|(?===))|((?<=~=)|(?=~=))");`. Produces an array consisting of: `[fare.details.type, !=, "AB"]`.

Comment: Or even simpler `split("(?<=[~=!]=)|(?=[~=!]=)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to extract the operator and the operands from each expression?
Maybe you should try de regex Pattern API.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.+)(==|\\!=|\\~=)(.+)");
    String string = "fare.details.type!=\"AB\";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    if (m.find()) {
        String fieldPath = m.group(1);
        String operator = m.group(2);
        String value = m.group(3);
    }
```